# Porting Android Library to BlackBerry 10

Tags: android, jar, blackberry, blackberry-10

we've developed our own library for Android development, which other developers can use for their own apps. Is it possible to use e.g. that .jar file or to port it for BlackBerry 10? So that BlackBerry developers could integrate it in their own apps? I have no experience with BlackBerry 10 development, but I know it's possible to run apk files on BlackBerry devices.

Any help and hints appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to port your library to C/C++, for use in creating native BB10 apps? Otherwise, while BB10 can run Android apps in its Android runtime, that would still be an Android app and an Android library. IOW, you may wish to explain in greater detail the nature of the library and the nature of your proposed port.

Comment: Please go through the steps mentioned in site https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_android_studio_plugin_tool.html

Comment: @Don I'd like to reuse that .jar file (can be integrated in own android apps) for BlackBerry 10. Otherwise I would have to dig into BlackBerry development and learn how to develop apps for BlackBerry and other stuff. The question is, if e.g. a jar file which contains Android specific API calls, could be used as well for BlackBerry

Comment: I think this usecase is for porting apk files to bar files. But I have no apk. I'd like to reuse an Android Library project for Blackberry development, if possible

Comment: "a jar file which contains Android specific API calls, could be used as well for BlackBerry" -- the answer is the same as if you asked "an APK file which contains Android specific API calls, could be used as well for BlackBerry". The fact that the "Android specific API calls" happen to be in a JAR used by an APK, instead of in Java source code used by an APK, is immaterial. It then gets down to whether the **specific** "API calls" are supported by BB10's Android runtime. We do not know what those calls are. You'll have to [read the documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/).

Comment: @sNore: "But I have no apk" -- then nothing will use your JAR. A JAR file is used in compiling an Android APK. Native BB10 development is in C/C++, not Java.

Comment: Ok, my question is confusing.. I better had to ask, if it's possible to reuse jar files with android code for blackberry 10 development. But I'm new to BlackBerry dev

Comment: Again, you need to decide *in what language* you are doing the BB10 development. There are [three runtimes](http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/bb10.html) in addition to native C/C++ development that BB10 supports. Only the Android runtime would use a JAR, and that only for writing an Android app (APK) that would run on BB10. If you are writing in C/C++, ActionScript (AIR), or HTML/CSS/JS, you cannot use a JAR and would need to port the code to the new language and environment.

Comment: Ok thx. I've figured out that we have a .aar library for Android. I think i will have to make a native c/c++ static or shared library.

Comment: That will require a full-on port to C/C++. There's no way that you are going to use an AAR for native BB10 development.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The intent is, that other BB10 developer will be able to use that library for their own BB10 apps.

Answer (score 2):

@sNore what are you thinking, is not possible because BB10 use C/C++(QT,cascades,and QNX)  API. none of these API are supported by android(as you mention as .jar). you can utilize your library project/Code/jar in your different android project and then port your app's .apk file to BB10 using as  @Don mentioned tool.